# Concatenating 2 values from 2 consecutive recordsets | MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, concatenation

I want to get the data from 1 SQL query of a table with 2 values

```
 select c from tmp;

    c 
   foo  
   bar 

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The returned data I need is <foo,bar>

Concat does not do this nor does any string function I can find. I can SUM integers from 2 lines. Why can't I retrieve the string values likewise?

Comment: I assumed you are using TSQL. But if you are using MYSQL you are better off with `Group_CONCAT()`, please specify your DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to get values together.

**This will combine all the string values separated by comma**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need a `group_concat()` in MYSQL.

Noticing that you need in MYSQL here a sample:

*** [SQLFIDDLE demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81967/1)**

```
Select department, group_concat(name,',') as nameList
from foo
group by department
;
```

Results:

```
Department NameList
D1         John, Mary
D2         Tim, Dan, Jack
D3         Kate, Felix
```

Following is a method to use in TSQL:

You can try the following sample code and adjust it for your table/columns:

```
SELECT department, namelist = STUFF(
 (SELECT ','+ Name FROM foo B 
 WHERE b.department = a.department FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
FROM foo A
```

Or else you may do a `CTE`.